# Want to detect telecom operator name for current data setting in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to detect current gprs/3g operator name in android.

```
TelephoneManager.getNetworkOperator()
```

Is there in android API , what will be the case of dual SIM .

If there is SIM1-Airtel and SIM2-Vodafone

I want to know which data(gprs/3g) connection of SIM is in use.

Please suggest